# zsh: Add a warning to the prompt is a specific condition is met

Tags: command-prompt, zsh

## My case

I am working on a remote machine which accesses AWS. I have 3 `.aws/credential` files:

```
credentials
dev-credentials
root-credentials
```

When I want to use my root credentials, I use the following `.zshrc` aliases:

```
alias rootcert="cp ~/.aws/root-credentials ~/.aws/credentials"
alias devcert="cp  ~/.aws/dev-credentials  ~/.aws/credentials"
```

## My problem

Using root certificates is dangerous, and I would like a strong visual command prompt indication that I'm using it. The condition to test that is simple - whether the content of `~/.aws/root-credentials` equals the one of `~/.aws/credentials`.

## My question

How can I add a (bold red!) text to my prompt whenever two files are identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach to managing the cert files may be using symlinks.
Let me construct a setup very similar to yours that you can adapt.
You can just enter all of these right into your Zsh session.

```
cd tmp
touch creds-dev creds-root
ln -s creds-root creds-active
```

These are named with a consistent *creds* prefix to show up together in a
listing.

Now you have a symlink that you can change at-will to point to one or
the other.  E.g., to make the dev version active:

```
ln -sf creds-dev creds-active
```

A function that can check which is active uses `readlink` to follow
the symlink, and looks like:

```
certdetect() { [[ $(readlink creds-active) == "creds-root" ]] &&
    print -P '%K{red}%BROOTCERT%b%k ' || print }
```

The `-P` tells `print` to process prompt characters.  The `%K` is for
setting background; `%B` is bold.  The `%b` and `%k` turn them back
off.  The net results is a bold red `ROOTCERT`.  This is testable now;
just try calling it.

A Zsh prompt calls a `precmd` function before each rendering.  Use it
to add your call to `certdetect` and set a variable based on it:

```
precmd() { PR_ROOTCERT=$(certdetect) }
```

Then you can set your prompt to include the dynamic variable.  An
example prompt that features only that:

```
PROMPT='$PR_ROOTCERT%# '
```

Once you have all this working, you'll want to add its pieces to your
active `prompt_«whatever»` file.

Comment: Beautiful answer, and soft links are definitely the way to go. I'll try it.